# MySQL: How to modify a column to add property "On Delete Cascade"?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, alter-table

I'm trying to add `on delete cascade to a foreign key`. I've have tried the below but can not get it to work:

```
mysql> alter table visits modify fk_targets_visits on delete cascade;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on delete cascade' at line 1
mysql> alter table visits v modify v.fk_targets_visits on delete cascade; // same error
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD CONSTRAINT YOUR_CONSTRAINT
FOREIGN KEY (YOUR_FK)
REFERENCES TABLE_NAME (YOUR_FK)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: it is already a foreign key, I just want to set `on delete cascade`. should I remove the column and re-add it then?

Comment: Yes.first you need to drop the existing foreign constraint and recreate it by using above query .